# Regular Expression Date format m/dd/yy-m/dd/yy

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a regular expression in Javascript that matches a `m/dd/yy-m/dd/yy` format ( so it should look like `4/11/12-5/12/13`). I have tested my first section, and it seems to wok, however I cannot seem to get past the first section. Here is what I have (it will work for `4/11/12`, but not for `-5/12/12`:

```
var myDateRE = /^((0?[13578]|10|12)(-|\/)(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12])([0-9]?)|(3[01]?))(-|\/)((19)([2-9])(\d{1})|(20)([01])(\d{1})|([8901])(\d{1}))|(0?[2469]|11)(-|\/)(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12])([0-9]?)|(3[0]?))(-|\/)((19)([2-9])(\d{1})|(20)([01])(\d{1})|([8901])(\d{1})))[-]$/ ;
```

Comment: Holy spaghetti, Batman! Wouldn't it be easier to `.split('-')` the string and test each half separately?

Comment: @Juhana - beat me to it! A far easier approach than regex craziness

Answer (score 0):

This to find your substring

```
1?\d\/[01]\d\/\d{2}-1?\d\/[01]\d\/\d{2}/
```

You can add some brackets to determine each value

```
/(1?\d)\/([01]\d)\/(\d{2})-(1?\d)\/([01]\d)\/(\d{2})/.exec('4/11/12-5/12/13')
```

output

```
["4/11/12-5/12/13", "4", "11", "12", "5", "12", "13"]
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/BeCN6/)

```
var re = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}$/
var str = "4/11/12-5/12/13"

function testDate(str) {
  var parts = str.split("/");
  var date = new Date(str);
  return parts[0] == date.getMonth()+1 && 
         parts[1] == date.getDate()    && 
         parts[2] == String(date.getFullYear()).substring(2);
}

if (str.match(re)) {
    alert(testDate(str.split("-")[0]));
    alert(testDate(str.split("-")[1]));
}
```